# $f(y)+\arctan(y)$ is constant

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Suppose
$$
f(y)=\int_0^\infty e^{-yx}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\,dx
$$
then show that $f(y)+\arctan(y)$ is constant and use this result to show that 
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{x}}{x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$

MY THOUGHTS: So clearly we have to show that $f(y)+\arctan(y)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $y$ so that 
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}=f(0)+\arctan(0)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{x}}{x}\,dx,
$$
but I have no idea how to begin to combine these two expressions to get the desired result. Any thoughts?

Comment: Compare derivatives and send $y\to 0+$ for the second part.

Comment: You need to use the fact that $\arctan(x)+\arctan(\frac{1}{x}) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ (for x positive)

Comment: @Tryss: So I need to show that $f(y)=\arctan(1/y)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prove (using Dirchlet's test, for example) that $f(y)$ and $\int_0^\infty -e^{-yx}\sin x\, dx$ are uniformly convergent for $y > 0$ to justify

$$f'(y) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial y} e^{-yx} \frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx = \int_0^\infty -e^{-yx}\sin x\, dx, \quad y > 0.$$

Compute

$$\int_0^\infty -e^{-yx}\sin x\, dx = -\frac{1}{1 + y^2}.$$

Since $f'(y) = -\frac{1}{1 + y^2}$, $f(y) = -\arctan(y) + C$, where $C$ is a constant. Show that $\lim\limits_{y\to \infty} f(y) = 0$ to deduce $C = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Let $y\to 0^+$ to obtain $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx = f(0+) = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$ g(y) = f(y) + \arctan(y) \implies g'(y) = -\frac{1}{1+y^2} + \frac{1}{1+y^2}=0  $$

since $f'(y)=-\frac{1}{1+y^2}$ then you can conclude.